# Deploying Mobile Xamarin Apps Via MDM With Configurations

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

Have a Xamarin application that will be deployed to iOS, Android and Windows. This isn't a public application and would be distributed via private channels such as Apple Business Manager. (Don't know the Android equivalent yet)
The application requires a few configurations to point it to the right environment and some other related settings that change per environment.

My question is when the application is deployed via an MDM solution, can most MDM solutions deploy the application with configurations that can be set at deployment?

Where would these settings be written if it's an iOS application?
Would it be saved in NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults or in Essentials.Preferences or other?

Same questions above for Android? I'm not familiar with this side of the house yet.

Thanks in advance for any help or documentation you can supply.

**Update 1**

https://www.appconfig.org/ios/

I found the following which states it should use NSUserDefaults. The documentation link to Apple seems old but might still be correct with my previous assumption that it would be NSUserDefaults. Will need to find a way to test this and validate unless there is new documentation.

Comment: You mentioned Apple, so start with their relevant docs. I don't know anything about MDM, but I see [Apple - Intro to mobile device management, section "Configuration profiles"](https://support.apple.com/guide/deployment/intro-to-mdm-depc0aadd3fe/1/web/1.0).